# Why are common websites' HTML/CSS/Javascript code so complicated?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Here's an example. Here's the first line of Google.com's source code:

`<!doctype html><html itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" lang="en"><head><meta charset="UTF-8"><meta content="origin" name="referrer"><meta content="Search the world's information, including webpages, images, videos and more. Google has many special features to help you find exactly what you're looking for." name="description"><meta content="noodp" name="robots"><meta content="/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128dp.png" itemprop="image"><meta content="origin" name="referrer"><title>Google</title><script nonce="XjiG6ei3xpCzqSyqDw5UMQ==">(function(){window.google={kEI:'FVDQXsDdKIKJytMPnLiC2Aw',kEXPI:'31',u:'bec65bdf',kBL:'_A-L'};google.sn='webhp';google.kHL='en';})();(function(){google.lc=[];google.li=0;google.getEI=function(a){for(var c;a&&(!a.getAttribute||!(c=a.getAttribute("eid")));)a=a.parentNode;return c||google.kEI};google.getLEI=function(a){for(var c=null;a&&(!a.getAttribute||!(c=a.getAttribute("leid")));)a=a.parentNode;return c};google.ml=function(){return null};google.time=function(){return Date.now()};google.log=function(a,c,b,d,g)`

This goes on for lines, and lines, and lines... Why is this?
All that Google seems is a search engine, does it really take this much Javascript for it to work?

When scrolling through, about 96% of all the code is Javascript. My guess is most of the code is for connecting to cookies, ads, etc. but I'd like to get this verified. What else is the Javascript used for in this context?

Additionally, one "line" of code spans at least 15 columns on average. Why doesn't Google space things out? Is it for things to be more compact?

`function a(){var b=c,e=document.fonts.load(b+" 10pt "+font);google.wf&&e.then(function(){google.wf["e"+b]=Math.round(window.performance.now())})};if(document.fonts&&document.fonts.load)for(var d=l.split(","),f=0,c=void 0;c=d[f];++f)a();})();</script><div id="cst"><style>.z1asCe{display:inline-block;fill:currentColor;height:24px;line-height:24px;position:relative;width:24px}.z1asCe svg{display:block;height:100%;width:100%}.spch-dlg{background:transparent;border:none}.spch{background:#fff;height:100%;left:0;opacity:0;overflow:hidden;position:fixed;text-align:left;top:0;visibility:hidden;width:100%;z-index:10000;transition:visibility 0s linear 0.218s,background-color 0.218s}.close-button{background:none;border:none;color:#777;cursor:pointer;font-size:26px;right:0;height:11px;line-height:15px;margin:15px;opacity:.6;padding:0;position:absolute;top:0;width:15px;z-index:10}.close-button:hover{opacity:.8}.close-button:active{opacity:1}.spchc{display:block;height:42px;position:absolute;pointer-events:none}.inner-container{height:100%;opacity:.1;pointer-events:none;width:100%;transition:opacity .318s ease-in}.s2ml .inner-container,.s2ra .inner-container,.s2er .inner-container{opacity:1;transition:opacity 0s}.text-container{pointer-events:none}.s2fp-h .text-container,.s2fp .text-container,.s2fpm-h .text-container,.s2fpm .text-container{position:absolute}.s2tb-h .text-container,.s2tb .text-container{position:relative}.spcht{font-weight:normal;line-height:1.2;opacity:0;pointer-events:none;position:absolute;text-align:left;-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;transition:opacity .1s ease-in,margin-left .5s ease-in,top 0s linear 0.218s}.s2fp-h .spcht,.s2fpm-h .spcht{margin-left:44px}.s2tb-h .spcht{margin-left:32px}.s2fp-h .spcht,.s2fp .spcht,.s2fpm-h .spcht,.s2fpm .spcht{left:-44px;top:-.2em}.s2fp-h .spcht,.s2fp .spcht{font-size:32px;width:460px}.s2fpm-h .spcht,.s2fpm .spcht{font-size:28px;width:300px}.s2tb-h .spcht,.s2tb .spcht{font-size:27px;left:7px;top:.2em;width:490px}.s2fp .spcht,.s2fpm .spcht,.s2tb .spcht{margin-left:0;opacity:1;transition:opacity .5s ease-out,margin-left .5s ease-out}.spchta{color:#15c;cursor:pointer;font-size:18px;font-weight:500;pointer-events:auto;text-decoration:underline}.spch-2l.spcht,.spch-3l.spcht,.spch-4l.spcht{transition:top 0.218s ease-out}.spch-2l.spcht{top:-.6em}.spch-3l.spcht{top:-1.3em}.spch-4l.spcht{top:-1.7em}.s2fp .spch-5l.spcht{top:-2.5em}.s2tb .spch-5l.spcht{font-size:24px;top:-1.7em;transition:font-size 0.218s ease-out}.permission-bar{margin-top:-100px;opacity:0;pointer-events:none;position:absolute;width:500px;transition:opacity 0.218s ease-in,margin-top .4s ease-in}.s2wfp .permission-bar{margin-top:-300px;opacity:1;transition:opacity .5s ease-out 0.218s,margin-top 0.218s ease-out 0.218s}.permission-bar-gradient{box-shadow:0 1px 0px #4285f4;height:80px;left:0;margin:0;opacity:0;pointer-events:none;position:fixed;right:0;top:-80px;transition:opacity 0.218s,box-shadow 0.218s}.s2wfp .permission-bar-gradient{box-shadow:0 1px 80px #4285f4;opacity:1;pointer-events:none;animation:allow-alert .75s 0 infinite;animation-direction:alternate;animation-timing-function:ease-out;transition:opacity 0.218s,box-shadow 0.218s}@-webkit-keyframes allow-alert {from{opacity:1}to{opacity:.35}}.s2fp.spch{opacity:1;visibility:visible;transition-delay:0s}.s2tb-h.spch{background:rgba(255,255,255,0);opacity:0;visibility:hidden}.s2tb.spch{background:rgba(255,255,255,0);opacity:1;visibility:visible;transition-delay:0s}.google-logo{background:url(data:image/png;base64,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) no-repeat center;background-size:94px 32px;height:32px;width:94px;top:8px;opacity:0;float:right;left:255px;pointer-events:none;position:relative;transition:opacity .5s ease-in,left .5s ease-in}.s2tb .google-logo{opacity:0.54;left:270px;transition:opacity .5s ease-out,left .5s ease-out}.s2fp .spchc,.s2fp-h .spchc{margin:auto;margin-top:312px;max-width:572px;min-width:534px;padding:0 223px;position:relative;top:0}.s2tb .spchc,.s2tb-h .spchc{background:#fff;box-shadow:0 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.2);margin:0;min-width:100%;overflow:hidden;padding:51px 0 50px 126px;position:absolute}.s2tb-h .inner-container,.s2tb .inner-container{height:100%;width:572px;transition:opacity .318s ease-in}.button{background-color:#fff;border:1px solid #eee;border-radius:100%;bottom:0;box-shadow:0 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.1);cursor:pointer;display:inline-block;left:0;opacity:0;pointer-events:none;position:absolute;right:0;top:0;transition:background-color 0.218s,border 0.218s,box-shadow 0.218s}.s2tb-h .button{left:-83px;opacity:0;pointer-events:none;position:absolute;top:-83px;transition-delay:0}.s2fp-h .button,.s2fpm-h .button{opacity:0;pointer-events:none;position:absolute;transition-delay:0}.s2fp .button,.s2tb .button,.s2fpm .button{opacity:1;pointer-events:auto;position:absolute;transform:scale(1);transition-delay:0}.s2ra .button{background-color:#f44;border:0;box-shadow:none}.r8s4j{background-color:#dbdbdb;border-radius:100%;display:inline-block;height:301px;left:-69px;opacity:1;pointer-events:none;position:absolute;top:-69px;width:301px;transform:scale(.01);transition:opacity 0.218s}.s2tb-h .r8s4j,.s2tb .r8s4j{height:151px;left:-28px;top:-28px;width:151px}.button-container{pointer-events:none;position:relative;transition:transform 0.218s,opacity 0.218s ease-in}.s2fp-h .button-container,.s2fp .button-container{height:165px;right:-70px;top:-70px;width:165px;float:right}.s2fpm-h .button-container,.s2fpm .button-container{height:165px;margin:0 auto;top:150px;width:165px}.s2fp-h .button-container,.s2tb-h .button-container,.s2fpm-h .button-container{transform:scale(.1)}.s2fp .button-container,.s2fpm-h .button-container,.s2tb .button-container{transform:scale(1)}.s2tb-h .button-container,.s2tb .button-container{height:95px;right:-31px;top:-27px;width:95px;float:right}.s2ra .button:active{background-color:#cd0000}.button:active{background-color:#eee}.microphone{height:87px;left:43px;pointer-events:none;position:absolute;top:47px;width:42px;transform:scale(1)}.s2tb-h .microphone,.s2tb .microphone{left:17px;top:7px;transform:scale(.53)}.receiver{background-color:#999;border-radius:30px;height:46px;left:25px;pointer-events:none;position:absolute;width:24px}.wrapper{bottom:0;height:53px;left:11px;overflow:hidden;pointer-events:none;position:absolute;width:52px}.stem{background-color:#999;bottom:14px;height:14px;left:22px;pointer-events:none;position:absolute;width:9px;z-index:1}.shell{border:7px solid #999;border-radius:28px;bottom:27px;height:57px;pointer-events:none;position:absolute;width:38px;z-index:0;left:0px}.s2ml .receiver,.s2ml .stem{background-color:#f44}.s2ml .shell{border-color:#f44}.s2ra .receiver,.s2ra .stem{background-color:#fff}.s2ra .shell{border-color:#fff}</style></div><style>@media only screen and (max-width:580px){#gb div{display:none}}#gb{font-size:13px}#hptl{position:absolute;margin:7px 0 0 10px}#hptl a{display:inline-block;padding-left:15px;color:#000;opacity:0.75}#gb{position:relative;top:8px}div#searchform{min-width:980px;z-index:127}div.sfbg,div.sfbgg{min-width:980px;height:64px}.big form#tsf,form#tsf{width:auto;max-width:784px;overflow:hidden}#searchform.big>#tsf{max-width:784px}.big div.tsf-p,form>div.tsf-p{margin:-1px 0 0;padding-right:0}#gb{top:16px}div#viewport{position:absolute;top:0;width:100%}div#searchform.jhp{margin-top:0}#searchform.big.jhp>#tsf{max-width:none}.jhp>#tsf{max-width:none}</style> <div id="gb"> <div id="hptl"> <a href="https://about.google/?fg=1&amp;utm_source=google-US&amp;utm_medium=referral&amp;utm_campaign=hp-header" ping="/url?sa=t&amp;rct=j&amp;source=webhp&amp;url=https://about.google/%3Ffg%3D1%26utm_source%3Dgoogle-US%26utm_medium%3Dreferral%26utm_campaign%3Dhp-header&amp;ved=0ahUKEwiAvPrP4dfpAhWChHIEHRycAMsQkNQCCAM">About</a> <a href="https://store.google.com/US?utm_source=hp_header&amp;utm_medium=google_ooo&amp;utm_campaign=GS100042&amp;hl=en-US" ping="/url?sa=t&amp;rct=j&amp;source=webhp&amp;url=https://store.google.com/US%3Futm_source%3Dhp_header%26utm_medium%3Dgoogle_ooo%26utm_campaign%3DGS100042%26hl%3Den-US&amp;ved=0ahUKEwiAvPrP4dfpAhWChHIEHRycAMsQpMwCCAQ">Store</a> </div> <div id="gbw">   <div style="top:0;left:0;right:0;width:100%"> <div class="gb_Xa gb_Ng gb_i gb_Mg gb_Qg" data-ogsr-up=""><div class="gb_ne gb_i gb_Ng gb_Dg" data-ogbl=""><div class="gb_h gb_i"><a class="gb_g" data-pid="23" href="https://mail.google.com/mail/?tab=wm&amp;authuser=0&amp;ogbl" target="_top">Gmail</a></div><div class="gb_h gb_i"><a class="gb_g" data-pid="2" href="https://www.google.com/imghp?hl=en&amp;tab=wi&amp;authuser=0&amp;ogbl" target="_top">Images</a></div></div><div class="gb_3c gb_Ng gb_i"><div class="gb_C gb_md gb_i" data-ogsr-fb="true" data-ogsr-alt="" id="gbwa"><div class="gb_Vf"><a class="gb_D gb_xc" href="https://www.google.com/intl/en/about/products?tab=wh" title="Google apps" aria-expanded="false" role="button" tabindex="0"></a></div></div><div class="gb_Sa gb_md gb_Ng gb_i gb_Wf"><div class="gb_Vf gb_Wa gb_Ng gb_i"><a class="gb_D gb_Ra gb_i" href="https://accounts.google.com/SignOutOptions?hl=en&amp;continue=https://www.google.com/" role="button" tabindex="0" title="Google Account: &#10;(sirswagger21@gmail.com)"><span class="gb_Ia gbii" aria-hidden="true"></span></a><div class="gb_5a"></div><div class="gb_4a"></div></div></div></div></div> </div> </div> </div>  <div class="jhp" id="searchform"><script nonce="XjiG6ei3xpCzqSyqDw5UMQ==">(function(){var _j=1280;try{var s=document.getElementById('searchform');var w=document['body']&&document.body['offsetWidth'];if(s&&w&&w>=_j){s.className+=' big';document['body'].className+=' big';}`

That entire blob is from one line alone. Most of it is Javascript with some HTML/CSS mixed in there too. Again, why is this? Isn't it harder to read than normal, spaced out code?

I'm a beginner coder who started HTML/CSS a few months ago and just started Javascript, so I'm still yet to learn a lot.

Comment: *Is it for things to be more compact?* Yes. If Google *didn't* minify their code, that'd probably translate to thousands of dollars more spent on hosting costs. Less bandwidth = less load = fewer servers to purchase and maintain - a reasonable consideration for what may be the most popular site on the internet.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Thanks for answering my second point. What about the stuff actually _in_ the code? What is the bulk of it actually for? I can't imagine it going all to the Google engine only.

Comment: actually 99% of it is spyware and has nothing to do with search service.

Comment: Jason Youm, it is kind of hard to understand why Google, Microsoft, Apple, and other companies do these types of things. But we do understand that they are big corporations, and they probably need more things done on their site than lots of other people do on theirs'. I've looked at the source code of these sites a lot (often to get ideas), and have noticed the same. Also, since many of the workers at these companies probably know whole lots of different things in HTML, CSS, JavaScript, PHP, etc, and therefore, they used that knowledge to their advantage. But they do the same just complicated.

Comment: May I ask why they make their HTML element id's so complicated? Is that also part of the minification process?

Comment: You're going to love this http://www.jsfuck.com/
Obfuscation is another reason sometimes

Comment: You may want to look at systems such as [React](https://reactjs.org/) which "compiles" JavaScript code so it works in many browsers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's called `minification`.

Typically production deployment of code will go through multiple processes -  one of them being `bundling` which will almost always have a step for `minifying` all the scripts file.

And, you're right that it's harder to read. But this code that's deployed on production is not meant to be read. The developers will be having access to the un-minified development codebase (which they can deploy to intranet servers to test and develop).

All the JavaScript that is found in the code could be for many things, including ads. These script are probably not entirely for cookies because, to write a cookie, you only need to add `document.cookie = "username: johndoe"`, or something similar.

Comment: Thank you. What about the contents of the script itself? Is the javascript all for the search engine, or is it for other things like ads, spyware, cookies, etc?

Comment: It would mostly be having cookie handling, and other stuff required at client side - like user interactions. Most of the search related code will be on the server. Also, I'm not sure trying to understand minified code is the best way to learn.